# Помогите найти ошибку в коде pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

Заставили делать дз на паскале, но почему-то результат получается разным, пишу от силы 2 раз в жизни и не могу понять где ошибка. Смысл задачи это поиск праймориала (произведение n простых чисел).

Рабочий код на c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool simple(int n) {
    int sqr;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    sqr = sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqr; i++) {
        if ((n % i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    int i = 2, temp = 0, sum = 2;
    while (true) {
        if (simple(i)) {
            sum *= i;
            temp++;
        }
        i++;
        if (temp == n-1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;

}
```

Не рабочий на паскале:

```
program Zantoryu;
function simple(n:integer): integer;
begin
  var sqr:real;
  if n mod 2 = 0 then
    Result := 0;
  sqr := sqrt(n);
  var i:integer;
  i := 3;
  while i <= sqr do 
  begin
    if (n mod i) = 0 then
      Result := 0;
    i := i + 1;
  end;
Result := 1;
end;

var res:BigInteger;
var onigiri, n, temp, i:integer;

begin
readln(n);
temp := 0; i := 2; onigiri := 2;
while true do
begin
  if simple(i) = 1 then
     onigiri := onigiri * i;
     temp := temp + 1;
i := i + 1;
  if temp = n-1 then
    break;
end;

writeln(onigiri);
end.
```

Как я понял проблема в функции, но как не пробовал решить не получилось, при вводе 4 выдает 48, а не 210

Comment: Учтите, что при `n==2` ваша проверка на простоту выдаст неверный ответ...

Comment: @Harry понял, спасибо, исправлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (n mod i) = 0 then
begin
  Result := 0;
  exit; // <---
end;

...

if simple(i) = 1 then
begin
  onigiri := onigiri * i;
  temp := temp + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Все заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: @roronoa Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: нажал, и еще можно у вас спросить, а если мне нужно выдавать предупреждение при значении больше чем 10 в 100 степени, то как это сделать, если я получаю ошибку Program1.pas(45) : Операция '<' не применима к типам real и System.Numerics.BigInteger

Comment: из-за этой строки - if exp(ln(10)*100) < onigiri then

Comment: @roronoa Я ничего не понял. Но наверное, надо задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338081/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-10-%d0%b2-100-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]