# Нужно выдать предупреждение при значении больше 10 в 100 степени

Tags: pascal

Я использую BigInteger и мне нужно сравнить свой результат с 10 в 100 степени и выдать предупреждение. Я пробовал сделать так

```
var onigiri, b:BigInteger;

...

b := 100000000000000000000000000000000000..; или exp(ln(10)*100)

...

if b < onigiri then begin

...
```

Но получал такие ошибки

```
Program1.pas(31) : Слишком большое целое


Program1.pas(31) : Нельзя преобразовать тип real к System.Numerics.BigInteger
```

Comment: может добавить суффикс bi надо к числу.

Comment: @xmikex так b := (BigInteger) 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; ?

Comment: если вы используете BigInteger, то, несомненно, нужно прочитать, как в нём задаются константы (я не знаю, что это за модуль - возможно, из какого-то экзотического Паскаля)

Comment: roronoa, для числа справа не указано, что оно должно быть BigInteger - поэтому по дефолту оно становится real, а потом происходит попытка преобразовать real к BigInteger при присваивании.
b := 100000000000000000000000000000000000bi;

Comment: @xmikex вроде понял, но как это сделать в паскале? пишу 2 раз от силы просто и ничего найти не могу об этом

Comment: ну я написал же суффикс bi -  это ты в конце числа добавляешь, а не перед числом - то что ты написал.
t:=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bi

Comment: @xmikex только что проверил и то же самое т.т - Program1.pas(31) : Слишком большое целое

Comment: а у вас какая версия паскаля? Просто литералы для BigInteger введены в версии  3.7.2

Comment: pascal 3.8, вроде

Comment: я не знаю как точно посмотреть, но та что с PascalAbc.NET 3.8 идет

Comment: надо использовать BigInteger.Parse для задания чисел больше размера int.
b:=BigInteger.Parse('100000000000000000000000000000');

Comment: @xmikex заработало! Огромное вам спасибо, оставьте ответ хоть, я как правильный отмечу тогда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте BigInteger.Parse('строка с числом')

> Для каждого целого типа T определены статические функции: T.Parse(s) -
> функция, конвертирующая строковое представление числа в значение типа
> T.